# How can I replace a snowball with a custom creeper?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to use the /execute command and replace a snowball with a creeper, using this command:

```
/summon Creeper {Fuse:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:11,Duration:10000,ShowParticles:0b},{Id:7,Amplifier:"0",Duration:10000,ShowParticles:1b}],Attributes:[{Name:generic.maxHealth,Base:2}],Silent:0,Riding:{id:"FallingSand",Riding:{Fuse:1,id:"Creeper",ActiveEffects:[{Id:7,Amplifier:"0",Duration:10000,ShowParticles:0b},{Id:14,Amplifier:"0",Duration:10000,ShowParticles:0b}],Attributes:[{Name:generic.maxHealth,Base:10}],Riding:{id:"FallingSand",Riding:{Fuse:1,id:"Creeper",Attributes:[{Name:generic.maxHealth,Base:10}],ActiveEffects:[{Id:7,Amplifier:"0",Duration:100000,ShowParticles:0b},{Id:14,Amplifier:"0",Duration:10000,ShowParticles:0b}],Riding:{id:"FallingSand",Riding:{Attributes:[{Name:generic.maxHealth,Base:10}],id:"Creeper",Fuse:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:7,Amplifier:"0",Duration:100000,ShowParticles:0b},{Id:14,Amplifier:"0",Duration:100000,ShowParticles:0b}],Riding:{id:"FallingSand",Riding:{ActiveEffects:[{Id:7,Amplifier:"0",Duration:10000,ShowParticles:0b},{Id:14,Amplifier:"0",Duration:10000,ShowParticles:0b}],id:"Creeper",Attributes:[{Name:generic.maxHealth,Base:10}],Fuse:1,Riding:{id:"FallingSand"}}}}}}}}}}
```

However, it's not working. It only spawns one creeper with no custom effects. What's wrong?

Comment: Is there any error in chat or inside the command-block GUI?

Comment: Nope, is says that it was successfully summoned

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the coordinates for the `/summon` command:

```
/summon <entity> X Y Z {dataTags}
```

One very minor issue is the use of quotation marks around the value for `Amplifier`, which causes it to have a tag-type of String rather than the numerical tag-type it's looking for (specifically Byte, though with `/summon` it can be declared as any numerical type). The tag is essentially ignored, but since it's intended to be 0, it doesn't matter as that's the default.

Fixed command:

```
/summon Creeper ~ ~1 ~ {Fuse:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:11,Duration:10000,ShowParticles:0b},{Id:7,Amplifier:"0",Duration:10000,ShowParticles:1b}],Attributes:[{Name:generic.maxHealth,Base:2}],Silent:0,Riding:{id:"FallingSand",Riding:{Fuse:1,id:"Creeper",ActiveEffects:[{Id:7,Amplifier:0,Duration:10000,ShowParticles:0b},{Id:14,Amplifier:0,Duration:10000,ShowParticles:0b}],Attributes:[{Name:generic.maxHealth,Base:10}],Riding:{id:"FallingSand",Riding:{Fuse:1,id:"Creeper",Attributes:[{Name:generic.maxHealth,Base:10}],ActiveEffects:[{Id:7,Amplifier:0,Duration:100000,ShowParticles:0b},{Id:14,Amplifier:0,Duration:10000,ShowParticles:0b}],Riding:{id:"FallingSand",Riding:{Attributes:[{Name:generic.maxHealth,Base:10}],id:"Creeper",Fuse:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:7,Amplifier:0,Duration:100000,ShowParticles:0b},{Id:14,Amplifier:0,Duration:100000,ShowParticles:0b}],Riding:{id:"FallingSand",Riding:{ActiveEffects:[{Id:7,Amplifier:0,Duration:10000,ShowParticles:0b},{Id:14,Amplifier:0,Duration:10000,ShowParticles:0b}],id:"Creeper",Attributes:[{Name:generic.maxHealth,Base:10}],Fuse:1,Riding:{id:"FallingSand"}}}}}}}}}}
```

Comment: OMG THX I LOVE YOU :DDD